# How to make the scrollView like the Apple AppStore "Featured Page"?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

So if you drag down on the Featured page of the AppStore, you can see the bottom part (I'm assuming its a tableView) moves while the top banner stays stuck. When you scroll down, the banner scrolls too. I have been messing around a lot trying to figure out what has been done here. I'm trying to make a similar design in my own application. I know I can do this all with a single tableview, but I don't want to reuse or load that top banner.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that's either a tabbed view or multiple subviews together. I mainly do OS X dev, so I'm not sure how tabbed views work on iOS

Comment: Can you explain the tabbed view? Currently, I have used a ScrollView (Hold the banner) and inside this I have a TableView (Holds the other details, like description and items) but the problem with this approach is, the two scrolls gets mixed up with each other.

Comment: Never mind, it's not a tabbed view. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564818/how-to-create-a-layout-like-featured-page-in-app-store?rq=1) SO question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I found the exact solution to my problem by searching around. I have posted it below. Thanks again. =)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it. Apparently its a Table HeaderView, and we just change the size on the fly using scrollViewDelegate. Pretty straightforward.

Here is the tutorial which adds a little more to that style:

http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/

Hope this helps who were struggling with similar situation. :D