# List with fixed header bounce effect like App Store

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make a `UITableView` with a fixed header, like the App Store, with the bounce effect below the header:

[image: App Store GIF]

I've tried a [UIScrollView with a UITableView with scrollEnabled NO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574815/2819864). Didn't work; it didn't make the bounce effect below the header:

[image]

My View: 
[image]

Comment: Your question is identical to the linked duplicate.  If you feel that the duplicate does not answer your question, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42120346/edit) your post to show your attempt an explain exactly what is "not working" with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JAL , I tried the answer for that question. As I stated in my question, it doesn't make the bounce effect below the header. This is all done with constraints, so I'm not sure what code you would like me to add to the question.

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad.  You explain that the answer in the linked question "doesn't work," but you don't show your attempt (post a screenshot of Interface Builder, upload a sample project, or even attempt to explain how your solution differers).

Comment: @JAL OK, I've posted a screenshot of what I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found one solution.
Basically I created a UITableView and a header, both with clear background color. Then I add a new view (with the same height that the header tableView has), between the controller view and tableView, positioned at the top. This new view is the header.
I then use the function scrollViewDidScroll to manage the position of the view that simulates the header.
This way I could achieve the bounce in the tableView below the header

I have made an example,  you can download it [here](https://github.com/DiegoQuimbo/TableViewBounceEffect)